# Decodable Generic with Swift 4

Tags: swift, generics, swift4, decodable

I'm using the new `Decodable` protocol introduced in Swift 4. 
Inside my unit test, I want to use a generic method that decodes a specific JSON file for a specific `Decodable` type.

I wrote the following function matching the `JSONDecoder` `decode` method:

```
 var jsonDecoder: JSONDecoder = {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        return decoder
    }()

    static let bundle: Bundle = {
        let testBundle = Bundle(for: Decodable.self)
        let sampleURL = testBundle.url(forResource: "api_samples", withExtension: "bundle")!
        return Bundle(url: sampleURL)!
    }()

    static func getJSONSample(fileName: String) throws -> Data {
        let url = Decodable.bundle.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json")!
        return try Data(contentsOf: url)
    }

 func assertDecode<Obj>(_ type: Obj.Type, fileName: String) where Obj: Decodable {
        do {
            let data = try Decodable.getJSONSample(fileName: fileName)

            let _ = try jsonDecoder.decode(type, from: data)
            // Same by using Obj.self, Obj.Type

        } catch let error {
            XCTFail("Should not have failed for \(type) with json \(fileName): \(error)")
        }
    }
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

`In argument type 'Obj.Type', 'Obj' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'`

I would have imagine that `Obj` is decodable due to the `where` clause.

What is wrong with that function?

Comment: How do you declare `Decodable.getJSONSample(fileName:)`?

Comment: Like this `static func getJSONSample(fileName: String) throws -> Data `

Comment: Where do you write it? The part `Decodable.getJSONSample(fileName: fileName)` cannot be compiled in my Xcode 9 beta 2.

Comment: It is not clear enough **where** you write your code, but seems very likely you have another `Decodable` type. Compiler takes the `Decodable` as yours, even if it is written in `where` clause. The `Decodable` in `where Obj: Decodable` is **your `Decodable`**, not the `Decodable` of Swift Standard Library.

Comment: You are right I had two `Decodable` class inside the project

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing a "where" statement, make your life easier by restricting the generic itself:

```
func assertDecode<Obj: Decodable>(_ type: Obj.Type, fileName: String)
```